# How can I use arabic numbering for theorems?

Tags: numbering, environments

I used the `newtheorem` command to create exercises in a book in the following way.

```
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Problems}
```

So in the body I use the following command to create a set of exercises,

```
\begin{xca}\label{ex1.3}{Problems}
```

The default numbering in this environment is roman. I would like to change it to arabic without having to go through each of the exercises in the book and modifying the enumeration command.

Here is a MWE. By creating a MWE, I noted why I was getting roman as oppose to arabic. My question now is whether I can still add something to the definition of `xca` so that enumeration is in Arabic and not in Roman.

```
\documentclass{cambridge7A}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]


\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Problems}

% remove the dot and change default for enumerated lists
\def\makeRRlabeldot#1{\hss\llap{#1}}
\renewcommand\theenumi{{\rm (\roman{enumi})}}
\renewcommand\theenumii{{\rm (\alph{enumii})}}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{{\rm (\arabic{enumiii})}}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{{\rm (\Alph{enumiv})}}


\begin{document}
\begin{xca}\label{ex1.3}{Problems}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Show that it follows from the definition of a field that zero, unit, additive, and multiplicative inverse scalars are all unique.
\end{enumerate}
\end{xca}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? There are multiple packages that provide support for creating theorems.

Comment: Thanks. By creating a MWE I noted the reason for Roman enumeration as oppose to Arabic.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @lmedina No problem. Sorry about the mistake I introduced in the title. Sorry Gonzalo; the fault is mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the representation for the first level of an `enumerate` environment, you can redefine `\theenumi`; the default definition on your example is

```
\renewcommand\theenumi{{\rm (\roman{enumi})}
```

so the label numbering will use lower-case Roman numerals; to get Arabic numbering you need to change it to

```
\renewcommand\theenumi{{\rmfamily(\arabic{enumi})}}
```

Since you want the change only to have effect inside the `xca` environment, one option would be to use `\AtBeginEnvironment` (from the `etoolbox` package) to make the change only inside the environment:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{xca}{\renewcommand\theenumi{{\rmfamily(\arabic{enumi})}}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{cambridge7A}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Problems}

% remove the dot and change default for enumerated lists
\def\makeRRlabeldot#1{\hss\llap{#1}}
\renewcommand\theenumi{{\rmfamily(\roman{enumi})}}
\renewcommand\theenumii{{\rmfamily(\alph{enumii})}}
\renewcommand\theenumiii{{\rmfamily(\arabic{enumiii})}}
\renewcommand\theenumiv{{\rmfamily(\Alph{enumiv})}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{xca}{\renewcommand\theenumi{{\rmfamily(\arabic{enumi})}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{xca}
\label{ex1.3}
Problems
\begin{enumerate}
\item Show that it follows from the definition of a field that zero, unit, additive, and multiplicative inverse scalars are all unique.
\end{enumerate}
\end{xca}

\begin{enumerate}
\item An item of an enumerated list outside the \texttt{xca} environment.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, this will change everything else in the book as well to Arabic where Roman was used. I just want to make changes in the exercises section without making changes elsewhere.

Comment: @lmedina then move the line inside the `xca` environment.

Comment: I really do not where to put it. I tried '\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Problems \renewcommand\theenumi{{\rm (\arabic{enumi})}}}'

Comment: @lmedina please see my updated answer. Will you always use the `xca` environment for problems? Should the modification be always used inside all `xca` environments?

Comment: Yes, I will always use xca for problems and inside the xca environment. So I would like to change the way I defined xca so that the numbering can change automatically wherever I used xca but elsewhere should not be affected.

Comment: @lmedina then please see the third option (the last one) that I presented in my answer.

Comment: would look nicer if the "(1)" were made `\upshape`.